# Folder Compression Issue using 7zip and powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, compression, archive, 7zip

I have a powershell script that will look for and compress log files then make a new .7zip file, however currently it has trouble compressing folder with dates e.g. application_logs_2016-07-14

1: The script works fine if there are folders with char's however if the containing folder has a date e.g. (application_logs_2016-07-14) nothing is archived.

2: I need a zip log files that are older than 5 days old, dump.log.341.log, dump.log.342.log and dump.log.343.log should be converted as dump.log.341.zip, dump.log.342.zip, dump.log.343.zip.

Here is the current code, if any powershell guru's could advise i'd be very happy. Thanks in advance.

```
# See if 7 zip is installed
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"}
set-alias sz "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe"

# Define log location and target directory
$Logfile = "D:\stuff\Software\dump files\Archive.log" 
$newdirectory = "D:\stuff\compressedlogs" 

# Write to log file - start of archive
$now = Get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
Add-Content $Logfile -value "Archive started $now"

# Import what we want to back up from a list file
$List = Import-CSV "D:\stuff\Software\dump files\Compressionlist.txt"

ForEach ($Entry in $List){

$filepath = $($Entry.FilePath)
$Extension = $($Entry.Extension)
$Include = $($Entry.Include)
$Horizon = $($Entry.Horizon)
$Ext2Chg = $($Entry.Ext2Chg)

# Extract List of Files to process
$log = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $filepath -Filter $Extension -Include $Include | Where-Object {$_.lastwriteTime -lt (((Get-Date).AddDays($Horizon)).date)}

# Archive each file found
ForEach ($file in $log) {

if ($file -ne $null) {

 $name = $file.name
$newdate = $file.CreationTime | Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd"
$newname = $file.BaseName + "___" + $newdate + $file.Extension
$directory = $file.DirectoryName
$zipfile = $newname.replace($Ext2Chg,".7z")
sz a -t7z "$newdirectory\$zipfile" "$directory\$name"
$now = Get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
Add-Content $Logfile -value "File $directory\$name archived to folder\new filename $newdirectory\$newname at $now"
Remove-Item $file
}

}

}

# Write to log file - end of archive
$now = Get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
Add-Content $Logfile -value "Archive completed $now"

# End
```

## The script looks at a txt document to find what to archive

**COMPRESSION LIST**

```
Filepath,Extension,Include,Horizon,Ext2Chg

E:\APPLICATION\DUMP_logs_*,*.log,APP.dumps-currentlog.messages*,-5,.log
```

===============================================================

example folder structure

**D:\application\server_log**

*(which will contain a log e.g. server_log_2016-07-14_00-00-00_0001.log)* this **will** archive fine.

**D:\application\application_log_2016-07-14**

*(which will contain a log e.g. APP.dumps-currentlog.messages.log)* this will **NOT** archive.

Hope that make sense.

Comment: How about to compress with semi-native methods? I believe in this case it will archive any folder as input: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/03/09/use-powershell-to-create-zip-archive-of-folder/

Comment: hmm ok... i'll look into it and see if it works out.   Thanks